# Remove specific header information sent from Thunderbird to Google servers

Tags: email, gmail

If I am using the web interface of Gmail, it doesn't add my IP address to the email headers (only adds the Google IP addresses). If I use Thunderbird, it add my IP address to it and Google mail servers forward this to the recipient who can see my IP address. Is there a way to change the headers Thunderbird sends?

PS: Please notice that you can already do this by sending the email from the web interface of Gmail.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about a header that starts

```
Received: from [x.x.x.x] (some.host.or.other. [x.x.x.x])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPSA id blahblahblah
```

then this header is added by Google and not by Thunderbird.  As far as I'm aware there's nothing you can do to stop Google's MTAs adding this header when they receive the incoming message from Thunderbird.

You could obfuscate your IP address with something like TOR, but the recipient would still get an IP address in the message headers -- it just wouldn't be yours.